# Displaying the backend generated error on the current view in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, browser-cache

I have a Spring MVC web application with JSP view pages. The user inputs values in certain input fields, uploads some files and on click of `Submit`, the inputs and the files get sent to backend and an output file gets generated and gets downloaded in the browser.

Backend validation on the input data might result in an error and I currently redirect to a separate central error page in that case which displays the error message. Now when user presses back button in the browser, he is send to the page with an empty form and needs to refill all the data and attach all files.

I tried maintaining state by rebuilding the same page in case of error and fill the form with entered inputs, displaying the error at the bottom in a `<div>`. This works well, but this requires making a separate page for each page on the website that can have a backend validation error. I also faced problem with the `choose file` buttons, since upon reconstruction of the page they won't link to the file on the user's system.

What is the cross browser compatible way of maintaining state in Spring MVC? Is there a better way to display error on same page without rebuilding it?

I am new to Spring MVC and Web development in general. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to learn about Ajax communication.  Asynchronous communication for form does not require a screen reload if only the verification results are delivered. It will also provide convenience to users.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. I am afraid spring tags don't provide native AJAX support. Currently the form is a spring's <form> tag and submits as POST request. Having AJAX to submit the form would mean doing away with native Spring's framework which is more robust. I used AJAX with Spring MVC to reload a particular div on a page. The div contained a table with links. These links did not always work once the div was reloaded via AJAX. So, I was skeptical of going in that direction. Please link to some examples of forms being submitted via AJAX in spring mvc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bit of a hack but you could add a message attribute to your `HttpSession` object the retrieve it in your various `RequestMapping`s, and add it to the `Model` object when you need it. Something like this:

```
    @RequestMapping("/example")
    public String example(HttpSession httpSession) {
//        You probably want something more dynamic but this is the general idea
        httpSession.setAttribute("errorMessage", "There was an error");
        return "example";
    }
```

Then in your error handler you can retrieve the message and add it to your Model like so:

```
 @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String error(@SessionAttribute("errorMessage") String errorMessage, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", errorMessage);
        return "error";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, I'm not sure how this saves me from rebuilding the page if I want to retain form data and display error on same view. The "error" view in your example is a separate page from the one on which the form was on, so the form data would still be lost in this redirection. Maybe I've misunderstood. Could you please elaborate.